# How to get rid of "Checkout Method" fields in WooCommerce Checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I try to remove "Checkout Fields" in Woocommerce checkout at my site, but probably dont use right class. So my question is how to remove complelety that form from checkout form. This is that form:

[image]

Link to [URL](http://www.pr4m.mx/tienda/) here.

Answer (score 0):

I just check the URL and can not see the member login options you can disable by guest checkout in woocommerce settings

[no-login-options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSNsO.png)